# How to slice a csr_matrix by certain list of rows/columns?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Suppose my csr_matrix is

```
I = [0, 1, 3 ,4 ,5, 0, 3]
J = [1, 3 , 4, 9 ,1 , 0, 8]
V = [1]*6
V.append(0)
data=sparse.coo_matrix((V,(I,J)),shape=(7,10)).tocsr()
```

which outputs

```
(0, 0)  1
(0, 1)  1
(1, 3)  1
(3, 4)  1
(3, 8)  0
(4, 9)  1
(5, 1)  1
```

So,I want to get entries with specific list of rows/columns. For example:

```
print(data[:,[3,5,8]])
(1, 0) 1
```

But I expected to get,

```
(1, 3)    1
(3, 8)    0
```

Similarly I want to get specific rows, but data[list:] does not give desired output. How can I solve this?

Comment: If you want to preserve explicit zeros, be prepared to do a lot of things manually. Most `scipy.sparse` operations make no guarantees about explicit zeros.

Comment: The result of that indexing is a (7,3) matrix, not the original (7,10).  Indexing reflects that.

Comment: yea, but how I can preserve the indexing tho?